# Nodejs/async not working properly with crontab

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cron

I have a script that needs to be executed every hour. The script has to download multiple large files from the internet.

The logic is simple.

1. An array of files to be downloaded.
2. Start download each in Serie (async.eachSerie)
3. After the download has finished go to next file in the array.

The problem is: I get the message "Your download has started" but I never get back the message 'Your download has finished'.

When I execute the script from command line works perfect. But it is not working with crontab (* * * * * node /path/script.js). The download never finishes.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: most likely a permission problem? which user's crontab are you using? where are you writing the file? why not log stderr to a file so that you can get the error message?

Comment: the user is the same when I use the console. And there is no error just don't download. I was thinking that crontab has timeout or something that I don't know :/